# How to exclude the first and second rows - Apps Script / Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Code I have allows me to automatically update the formulas in the sheet. It works.

On 1st row I have headers and they do not overwrite each other. In the 2nd I have the average formulas. Each edit overwrites entire column. Also those averages.

So I would like to exclude also 2nd row from pasting formulas.

```
function onEdit(e) {
var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet()
var tabs = ['2023'];
if(tabs.indexOf(activeSheet.getName()) !== -1){
var cell = e.range;
var col = cell.getColumn();
  if(cell.getFormula() !==""){
    var destination = activeSheet.getRange(3, col, activeSheet.getLastRow()-2, 1); 
cell.copyTo(destination);
    }
  }
}
```

I ask for your help.

I have tried to exclude 2nd row in the code, with no effect.

Comment: Welcome, could you please share a sample of your spreadsheet? As long as I've tried your code works excluding those two rows

Comment: I can verify what @Martín says - your code seems to be working as you say it should. The first two rows are ignored when anything in rows 3 and beyond is edited. Please share a sample of your spreadsheet.

Comment: Is it possible you have multiple `onEdit(e)` in your script file?  Perhaps the older version is still active?

Comment: Every function in a project must have a unique name.

Comment: This statement `var destination = activeSheet.getRange(3, col, activeSheet.getLastRow()-2, 1);` is copying the formula from the active cell to starting at row 3 so what doen't work?  Nothing in your script is writing to row 2.